# AtrributeError exception

Tags: django, exception, error-handling

I have a plugin with function:

```
def view(request):
        year = Entry.archive.aggregate(aggregator('pub_date_from'))\
                                                            .values()[0].year
        url = reverse('%s:blog_archive_year' % get_language(),
                      kwargs={'year': year})
        return redirect(url)
```

The problem is that while assigning `year` it looks at the first value. It works great if there is something in it, but if not - the `AttributeError` screams that `.values()[0].year` contains no data. I've tried to add try/exception but I realized that there is no `AtrributeError` in `django.core.exceptions`. How can I solve this problem? Giving a default value or something won't help since it's the part when it looks that throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`AttributeError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AttributeError) is a built-in exception, so you can just do:

```
try:
  year = Entry.archive.aggregate(aggregator('pub_date_from')).values()[0].year
  url = reverse('%s:blog_archive_year' % get_language(),
                  kwargs={'year': year})
  return redirect(url)
except AttributeError, e:
  return redirect(somewhere_else)
```

(i.e. you don't need to import anything to use `AttributeErro`, you can just use it).

Comment: Thanks, everything works right now :) Sorry for stupid assumption. Maybe you know any links where to find such already built-in exceptions or something like that?